# displaying field from node on page in url in block

Tags: blocks, users

I want to put a link in a block which will pull its url from a url field in the node being displayed on the page on which the block is. Meaning, the block will contain a different url for each different node-info page. How can I reference this node in the block?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it. Make a template file for that specific node ie: node-job.tpl.php and set the value of that url field (which is available to you while inside of that template file) as a global variable ie: variable_set. Now you can access the url inside of your block using variable_get.